# ng-grid set cellClass according to field value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm using the **[ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)** now and want the column to be displayed in **different color** according to different value, i've tried..but not success....

```
$scope.gridOptions =  { 
    ........
    columnDefs: [
        { field: "status", displayName: "Status", width:150,cellClass:"status" },
        { field: "",displayName: "Actions",cellClass: "actions",cellTemplate: "<a>xxxx....xxx</a>"}]
};
```

the ***status*** has two value, `success` or `failed`, and how can i set the `success` to `green` and `failed` to `red`, that means set the cellClass **dynamic**.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how to achieve this with cellClass attribute. You could add cellTemplate to your status row add your styles with [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and do something like this:

```
<div ng-class='status ? "success":"failed"'></div>
```

greetings